# How to remove All posts and Single User using Mongodb and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am kind of stuck at something, I am working on a personal blog that is full stack using mongodb with node.js and express. In that blog website only one user can sign up, and all posts are connected to that user. I am using the REST API to create a controller that deletes a user along with all the posts. I have the User and the Post object available and I was wondering if there is a way where I can use the User and Post schema objects to delete the user and ALL posts. I dont want to use the db.collection('posts') thing because I havent used that anywhere else. I went through mongodb node.js driver docs and I still cant figure out how to do it.

```
    exports.deleteUser = (req, res, next) => {

    User.find().then(user => {
        //what do i do here?
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        // you need to do next() otherwise error will not reach
        // our middlewear in app.js file
        next(err);
    })

    Post.find().then(allPosts => {
        if (!allPosts) {
            //what do i do here?
        }
        
        res.status(200).json({message: message})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        // you need to do next() otherwise error will not reach
        // our middlewear in app.js file
        next(err);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`deleteOne`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#deleteOne) and [`deleteMany`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#deleteMany) directly instead of using `find`.

Comment: So something like Post.deletemany({creator: userId}).then(result => { User.findbyIdAndDelete(userId).then().catch() ? would that be the correct way to chain the promises? i am a bit confused about how i should chain them, should i delete posts first and if that is successful and than delete user, or the other way around? or is there is there no difference to either approach?